# How to get the Tempdata in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this method in my Controller that saves the value in a Tempdata, as shown below.

```
public Boolean SaveSession(string id) {
        TempData["CurrentTab"] = id;
        return true;
    }
```

Now in my javascript, I want to get the value in that TempData. But when I alerted the value I got this value. "[object HTMLSpanElement]"

```
@{
         if (TempData["CurrentTab"] != null){           
            @:alert("" + @TempData["CurrentTab"].ToString())                
        }
    }
```

How can I get the string value of that Tempdata?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're wrapping your `TempData` value incorrectly.

Assuming your `id` is `my_span`, the JavaScript output is:

```
alert("" + my_span)
```

When you probably want:

```
alert("my_span")
```

The reason you see `[object HTMLSpanElement]` is because the Browser tries to translate `my_span` into `document.getElementById('my_span')` (since it doesn't know of any other `my_span`) and you actually have such (`span`) element with that id.

Try:

```
@{
     if (TempData["CurrentTab"] != null){
        @:alert('@(TempData["CurrentTab"])');
    }
}
```